# n|solid console: [WARNING] NSolid Agent shutting down, listening on port has encountered an error: EADDR │INUSE (address already in use)

Tags: nsolid

I successfully had n|solid + console + profiling running locally a day ago but when I restarted today, although I can get `etcd` and the `nsolid-proxy` up no problem, when I `npm start` in `nsolid-console` I am getting:

```
[WARNING] NSolid Agent shutting down, listening on port has encountered an error: EADDRINUSE (address already in use)
  on ../nsolid-ext/deps/agent/src/threads.cc:786

> nsolid-console@1.4.4 start /home/ns/nsolid-console
> NODE_ENV=production node bin/nsolid-console --interval=1000

[WARNING] NSolid Agent shutting down, listening on port has encountered an error: EADDRINUSE (address already in use)
  on ../nsolid-ext/deps/agent/src/threads.cc:786
Server running on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

...and when I do start my app with `nsolid index.js` and load the console at http://127.0.0.1:3000 and select my app, there are three processes running, instead of one, and they are: `npm`, `nsolid-proxy` and `nsolid` - as if the console is profiling nsolid itself and not my app.

Also, when I run `nsolid-cli ls` I have multiple entries...seems like I should only have one?

```
> nsolid-cli ls
{"pid":13143,"hostname":"rainworld","app":"example","address":"10.99.46.63:39682","id":"ec04fa6e98e08961bdba4f757d1cd2297563e4a6"}
{"pid":13908,"hostname":"rainworld","app":"example","address":"10.99.46.63:46188","id":"1fc5132d6b4f779a073b0ca8952862e165eb546a"}
{"pid":13095,"hostname":"rainworld","app":"example","address":"10.99.46.63:1111","id":"c2bddf9a505a490bab333e8b93627171586dbf6a"}
{"pid":13130,"hostname":"rainworld","app":"example","address":"10.99.46.63:42300","id":"b6b2a5a5c0da40ececc9ef0a0eed5fd4cd0927eb"}
```

I have all of the various env variables in my fish shell config file, e.g.

```
set -x NSOLID_APPNAME example
set -x NSOLID_HUB localhost:4001
set -x NSOLID_SOCKET 0
set -x NODE_ENV production
```

Comment: Hello Jerome, are you running `nsolid-console` and `nsolid-proxy` in a shell with `NSOLID_*` env variables set?

Comment: Yes, they were set globally in `.config/fish/config.fish` - I have tried removing those and instead setting them only when I start my app, but I still am getting the error when running `npm start` in `nsolid-console`.

Comment: You should have those variables only within your app, not in proxy and console, try running `unset` and restart all pieces and see if that works.

Comment: Yep, makes sense...I'll update soon with my results.

Comment: Yeah @julianduque, that was the info I needed. You should update this with an answer and I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSOLID_*` [environment variables](https://docs.nodesource.com/nsolid/1.2/docs/environment-configuration#key-environment-variables) should be set per application to be monitored, since you have this variables globally you are telling to the N|Solid runtime to monitor both the `nsolid-proxy` and `nsolid-console` under the same application name (defined in `NSOLID_APPNAME`).

Keep this variables locally per application and it should work.